# Is there a way to remove all but a few desired fields from a struct in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

So I have several structs that contains data that is used is a dozen or so scripts. The problem is that for each script I only need a handfull of variables and the rest I can ignore. I am using a massive amount of data (gigs of data) and MATLAB often gives me out of memory errors so I need to remove all unnecessary fields from the structs.

Currently I have a cell that contains all unneeded fields and then I call rmfield on the structs. But the fields in the structs often change and it is getting to be a pain to be constantly updating the list of unneeded fields. So is there a way to tell MATLAB to keep only those fields I want and remove everything else even if I don't know what everything else is?

Here is an example,

- Struct 1 has: A, B, C, D, E fields
- Struct 2 has: A, B, C, D, E, F fields
- Struct 3 has: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I fields

Sometimes Struct 3 might only have A thru G.

I want to keep only A, B, and C fields and remove all other data from all the structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy your struct's desired fields to a new variable in a function.

```
function newVar = getABC(strct)
    newVar.A = strct.A;
    newVar.B = strct.B;
    newVar.C = strct.C;        
end
```

`strct` will not be copied in memory beacuse [you will not be manipulating it](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/152).

> MATLAB uses a system commonly called "copy-on-write" to avoid making a
>   copy of the input argument inside the function workspace until or
>   unless you modify the input argument. If you do not modify the input
>   argument, MATLAB will avoid making a copy.

You can get `newVar` and then `clear strct` from memory.

---

Fred's generalized version:

```
function newVar = getFields(oldVar, desiredCell)
    for idx = 1:length(desiredCell)
    newVar.(desiredCell{idx}) = oldVar.(desiredCell{idx});
end
```

Comment: The struct may not be copied in the function workspace, but it must still be in memory in the main worspace. Therefor I think the minimum memory required is probably still the size of struct and newstruct.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin yes, but after leaving the function `strct` can be immediately removed from memory. Thus, only `newStrct` will occupy memory.

Comment: I like it, I'm going to use it. Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone is intersted, I used the answer but modified it somewhat to make it more generic.<br/> `function newVar = getFields(oldVar, desiredCell)<br/> for i=1:length(desiredCell)<br/> newVar.(desiredCell{i}) = oldVar.(desiredCell{i});<br/> end`<br/> This allows me to pass in any cell of strings of the variables I care about and get the data out. Thanks for the tip HebeleHododo!

Comment: @Fred that is a nice generalization. I edited it into my post.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way to do it:

1. Get the list of all fieldnames using `fieldnames`
2. Remove the ones that you want to keep from the list
3. Remove everything that is left in the list

---

Example

```
s.a=1
s.b=2
s.c=3
s.d='chitchat'

tokeep = {'a','b'}

f=fieldnames(s)

toRemove = f(~ismember(f,tokeep));

s = rmfield(s,[toRemove])
```

Comment: So I tried that using fieldnames() but couldn't figure out how to remove that ones that I wanted. I used a regular expression to do a search and replace but then rmfield obviously didn't like my replacement. Do you have any other suggestions for removing the strings from the cell?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: I've shortened your example a bit. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

1) Let's say you a have a structure S

2) You want to keep only the first three fields of S and delete all the others

```
fieldsS = fieldnames(S);
S = rmfield(S,fieldsS(4:end));
```

Answer (score 0):

The rmfield method in MATLAB is rather slow, so when dealing with large structures it is best to avoid it.

This MATLAB file exchange item: [kpfield](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/56413-kpfield--s--fields--) is basically the inverse of rmfield and should work exactly as you require.

It converts the structure to a cell array before keeping only the required indices by creating a logical array based on whether the fields exist in the fieldnames or not. The modified cell array is then converted back to a structure.

Disclaimer: I have written kpfield as I came across exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had success loading the struct- physically deleting fields I wanted to remove and then resaving the struct.

Deleting fields in the workspace does not delete them from the original struct - so resaving is necessary.